# Why isn't my PHP directing to my spanish site?

Tags: php, redirect, subdirectory

My code works for all my sites except the ones that begin with "es". Whenever I try to direct to those sites, it takes me back to index.html

This is my index.php code:

```
<?php 
/*
*
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
 *
 */
include "app/config.php";
include "app/detect.php";

if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='index.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='es/index.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/es/index.html';
}

else
    {
        include $browser_t.'/404.html';
    }

?>
```

I am linking [my site](http://test.elitecomps.com) so that you say what I mean. In the top right corner there is a hyperlink that says "Español" and when you click it, it's supposed to take you to a Spanish version of the page you're currently on. Instead, it simply takes you to the index tab anew and it changes the subdirectory, but my translated page does not appear.

Inside the config.php I have the following:

```
<?php
/*
 * 
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported
License URL: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
 *
 */
$current_page_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$part_url = explode("/", $current_page_uri);
$page_name = end($part_url);
$email_id = "support@elitecomps.com";
?>
```

And I would add my [detect.php](http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/c23a27b8defa25152327) code here but it is a large file and not the problem I am attempting to address so I will merely link it instead.

PS
Everything is linked appropriately and I have triple checked everything. My only suspect left is my index.php which I am unsure of why.

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: Well. I have successfully managed to obtain: `http://test.elitecomps.com/es/es/es/es/es/es/es/index.html` as my URL, i could go further with the eseseses

Comment: You need to switch 'es/index.html' to '/es/index.html' because I'm guessing $browser_t is changing from http://test.elitecomps.com to http://test.elitecomps.com/es and it's breaking.

Comment: And what's in config.php and detect.php?

Comment: I'm sorry @JayBlanchard but I did it that way because I felt it was simply a lot of code, however, I added all the code to it.

Comment: @taco I did, and it didn't seem to solve the problem. I already made the suggested change and reupdated the site, but the problem persists.

Comment: @andrewsi Why'd you mark my quesion as off-topic?

Comment: I added it to the prompt @JAL

Comment: I think that the problem here is that you take the name of the page and compare it with `es/index.html` wich is wrong because you take the last element in the url.

Comment: @HaveYouMetRandy you need to show us what $browser_t is set to. I'm starting to think you need to visit http://php.net/explode and read up what it does.

Comment: $page_name will never be es/index.html because you explode it by "/" and then retrieve the last part. It will become index.html in that case also, so it will redirect to /index.html. 
If your page has multiple html files which to load, this is not the correct way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$part_url = explode("/", $current_page_uri);
$page_name = end($part_url);
```

When the URL is "es/index.html", that code will assign `$page_name` to "index.html", since you're only interested in what is after the last `/`.

One way could be to check the end of the string by using `strrpos`, e.g.

```
if(strrpos("es/index.html", $current_page_uri) !== FALSE)
    // Go to spanish site
else if(strrpos("index.html", $current_page_uri) !== FALSE)
    // Normal index page
```

You could also check the second to last element in `$part_url` and check if it's "es", or any other language code.

Answer (score 0):

if I got your logic correctly, you should just use another condition here

replace:

```
if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='index.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='es/index.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/es/index.html';
}

else
    {
        include $browser_t.'/404.html';
    }
```

with

```
if ($current_page_uri=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($current_page_uri=='index.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($current_page_uri=='es/index.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/es/index.html';
}

else
    {
        include $browser_t.'/404.html';
    }
```

I think you was planning to use `$page_name` as detector. but the value you are trying to compare `es/index.html` is really your uri.